# Delete local printer before mapping

Tags: printing, vbscript

I have the following script that maps printers based on AD grouping:

```
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'-------------------------------MAPEAMENTO DE IMPRESSORAS-------------------------------------

on error resume next

'determines the user who just logged on
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set WSHNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
'As soon as we tack on LDAP:// and construct an ADsPath we then bind to the user account in
'Active Directory and report back the groups the user belongs to; this can be done simply 
'by enumerating the values in the MemberOf attribute.


strUserPath = "LDAP://" & Replace(objSysInfo.UserName, "/", "\/")
Set objUser = GetObject(strUserPath)


For Each objGroup in objUser.Groups
  strGroupName = objGroup.CN


    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '--------------MAPEAMENTO DE IMPRESSORA DO GRUPO UM-------------------------------------------

    'Mapeamento de impressoras por grupo definindo a impressora comom padrão para aquele grupo.
      Select Case strGroupName
         Case "GrupodoAD1"
        WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\servidor\impressora1"
        WshNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\servidor\impressora1"
      End Select

    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '--------------MAPEAMENTO DE IMPRESSORA DO GRUPO DOIS-----------------------------------------

    'Mapeamento de impressoras por grupo definindo a impressora comom padrão para aquele grupo.
      Select Case strGroupName
         Case "GrupodoAD2"
        WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\servidor\impressora2"
        WshNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\servidor\impressora2"
      End Select

    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  



    '==========Adicione seções adicionais de case para cada grupo do AD que tiver.+===============

    next
```

Now I was asked to delete some local printers on user's computers. The above script runs on logon. The condition although states that only certain printers must be deleted (some users take computers home and we do not want to delete their home printers).

Is there a way I can accomplish this using the above existing script? How can I do that and where do I insert the information? Can I delete more than 1 printer using a single script?

For example I know I must delete:

- Samsung SCX-6545X Series PCL 6
- Samsung SCX-6545X Series PCL 5
- Samsung SCX-6545X Series PS

If I have similar names like above, can I use that to delete any printer that matches parts of the name?

Best regards and thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Not here to write scripts for you.

Comment: Ok, that's your right. Although your comment was really not necessary.

Comment: It absolutely was. You posted a script that doesn't attempt to delete printers in the slightest in fact all it does is add some printers. You want help deleting printers show us the code you have attempted not just a  generic script that doesn't show that. See [ask] and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ok,understood and completelly see your point. But since the only script I could come up with is in Batch and it would not add anything valuable to my post I just did not put it in here.

I just don't think negative comments contribute in any aspect to the community as well. Perhaps pointing a newbie like me in the right direction like you did on your last comment could be a lot more productive.

I still feel like thanking you for pointing out that. Like I said, now I got what you meant.

Comment: That's fine but it is all a matter of perspective. For instance I can claim that posting an incomplete question that reads like a "give me code" question has a negative impact on the community. Admittedly my comment was a bit abrupt so for that I apologise.

Comment: Well, taking the blame here it is kind of what I did. But since a code is not something you'll lack after giving someone I don't see why someone should be mad. I mean, if you don't feel like sharing just don't. I usually like to share knolledge of things I master. VB unfortunatelly is not one of these things. I'm really sorry for causing such trouble here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a script I found from somewhere once and adapted slightly to delete printers by device name. Please approach with caution, understand it, and adapt it to your needs carefully:

```
On Error Resume Next

strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colInstalledPrinters = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Printer where DeviceID = 'HP LaserJet P1505'")

For Each objPrinter In colInstalledPrinters

    objPrinter.Delete_

Next
```

I think you could replace the equals clause in the "SELECT" statement to use a "IN" so you could check all the printers and delete them in one hit. Example:

```
("Select * from Win32_Printer where DeviceID In ('HP LaserJet P1505', 'Printer_2', 'Printer_3')")
```

Comment: I would be inclined to comment out `On Error Resume Next` until you are sure the script is working as expected.

Comment: No script for production use should have a globel OERN. Ever.

Comment: @Lankymart Thanks for the advice, will do that on a test computer and see how it goes>

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers Sorry but I'm not familiar with VB. What is a global OERN?

Comment: Global `On Error Resume Next`.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. It works for a single printer. When Trying to use SELECT with IN for more than one printer I get an error on "For Each objPrinter In colInstalledPrinters". Am I missing something? - @davy-c

Comment: Maybe someone else can jump in and see if an "IN" will work in that clause - this is not my area of expertise. If not, then you can always just delete them one-by-one (I would be inclined to do that anyway actually), in any case, I have answered your question.